# No access to SAMBA in stand alone mode

Tags: login, samba, file-sharing

We have a test server set up with SAMBA.  Passwords are encrypted, per default setup, but we can't connect to the test share from Windows or Mac clients.   I have nothing in the windows logs or samba log.machinename files.  There's nothing in the log.smbd files that corresponds to the time of the login failure.  When browsing to the share via Win7, we get the usual login window asking for domain\username and password.   I've tried using the SAMBA server's hostname, the workgroup name, and the domain of the client PC.  Nothing works and there are no errors.  Any ideas?   Thanks!

Comment: Also, I can connect from another Linux system using smbclient, so I know the service is up, listening, and accepting connections.

Comment: If you see nothing in the log.machinenames, then your server did not receive anything.  So it looks like the problem lies on the WIN7 side.  Could some kind of anti-virus software block the access?

Comment: We gutted the default SAMBA config and went with the bare minimum and now it works.

Comment: Current smb config is:  `# Global parameters
[global]
        map to guest = Bad User
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[demo]
        path = /smbtest/
        read only = No
`